# Running E2E conformance Tests within a custom cluster as a job

Tags: kubernetes, e2e-testing

I am thinking of running an e2e test as a job within my cluster Kubernetes cluster. So far I have the Makefile, the Docker Image created and image pushed to AWS. There are some tests that are currently failing which I am trying to debug but apart from that. Is there anything else I need to be aware of, any tips, hints or resources will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: You can take a look a my github example code, where I did something similar in OpenShift ;-) 
https://github.com/toschneck/openshift-example-bakery-ci-pipeline

Comment: I am not sure where exactly in your code you are referring to. :/

Comment: Could you help me with this question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169503/mounting-client-crt-client-key-ca-crt-with-a-service-account-or-otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I've ran Sonobuoy on a cluster and in parallel some simple load-testing.

I'm not sure exactly which test sonobuoy ran at the time but it was obvious the HTTP server I was testing had degraded performance.

So - If you want to have E2E running along side production workloads take into account it might effect users and services.