# Mounting client.crt, client.key, ca.crt with a service-account or otherwise?

Tags: kubernetes, e2e-testing, kubernetes-security

Has anyone used service-accounts to mount ssl certificates to access the aws cluster from within a running job before? How do we do this? I created the job and this is the from the the output of the failing container which is causing the Pod to be in error state.

```
Error in configuration:
* unable to read client-cert /client.crt for test-user due to open /client.crt: no such file or directory
* unable to read client-key /client.key for test-user due to open /client.key: no such file or directory
* unable to read certificate-authority /ca.crt for test-cluster due to open /ca.crt: no such file or director
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a `Secret` containing the certs, and then getting the job to reference it.

**Step 1.** Create secret:

```
kubectl create secret generic job-certs --from-file=client.crt --from-file=client.key --from-file=ca.crt
```

**Step 2.** Reference secret in job's manifest. You have to insert the `volumes` and `volumeMounts` in the job.

```
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: ssl
    secret:
      secretName: job-certs
  containers:
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/etc/ssl"
      name: "ssl"
```